# Read a json file and return json data

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx configuration file: `java.conf` below. What I really intend was when http://localhost:8080/home/abcd is visited then the JSON content in my /home/beatdata.json folder will be the return

```
upstream java{
    server java:8080;
    keepalive 32;
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name         localhost;
    gzip on;
    gzip_types '*';

    location / {
        keepalive_timeout 620;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_pass      http://java;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /home/abcd {
        root /home/;
        index beatdata.json;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `try_files /beatdata.json =404;` instead of the `index` statement.

Comment: It worked! Nice!